# I'm trying to call a double variable from one method into another

Tags: java, variables, methods, call

How do i call the length and width variable into the getArea method without creating a private variable in the class, the way I'm doing it is causing the method to run again after its already ran once. I really don't like it this way but thats the way the professor wants it done to simulate the times before "object oriented programming"

```
/*This program allows the user to enter the length and widtch and receive the area
 of the rectangle*/

 import java.util.Scanner;

public class theRectangleCompany
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print("This program will find an area of a Rectangle ");
    getLength();
    getWidth();
    getArea();
  }

  public static double getLength()
  {
    double length;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the length ");
    length = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return length;
  }

  public static double  getWidth()
  {
     double width;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Please enter the width ");
     width = keyboard.nextDouble();
     return width;
  }

  public static void getArea()
    {
      double length = getLength();
      double width = getWidth();
      double area = width * length;
      System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle is: " +area);

    }


}
```

Comment: You say you want to avoid using a private variable in the class, but what about a variable in the main method?

Comment: stephen, she only wants methods in the main, other than the message i prompt the user,

Comment: If methods have to only be called in main, my answer is definitely the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you calling getLength() and getWidth() from the main method. Just call getArea()

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print("This program will find an area of a Rectangle ");
    getArea();
  }
```

Comment: thats the way the professor wants it done for some reason, i agree! it works better if i do it that way

Answer (score 1):

You could make the getArea function take parameters, and use the function calls to the other two functions as the parameters:

```
getArea(getLength(), getWidth());

public static void getArea(double length, double width) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

**changes are here:**

```
/*This program allows the user to enter the length and widtch and receive the area
 of the rectangle*/

 import java.util.Scanner;

public class theRectangleCompany
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print("This program will find an area of a Rectangle ");    
    getArea();
  }

  public static double getLength()
  {
    double length;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the length ");
    length = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return length;
  }

  public static double  getWidth()
  {
     double width;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Please enter the width ");
     width = keyboard.nextDouble();
     return width;
  }

  public static void getArea()
    {
      double length = getLength();
      double width = getWidth();
      double area = (width * length);
      System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle is: " +area);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
public static void getArea()
{
  System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle is: " + (getLength() * getWidth()));
}
```

You'd also need to change the main method to exclude the getLength() and getWidth():

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.print("This program will find an area of a Rectangle ");
  getArea();
}
```

An variant to the above is something like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.print("This program will find an area of a Rectangle ");
  getArea(getLength(),getWidth());
}

public static void getArea(double length, double width)
{
  System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle is: " + (length * width));
}
```